# sql: how to find consecutive dates where condition is met in aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands, azure-sql-managed-instance

I am working in Azure SQL MI.  I am struggling with a certain SQL query.  I have a "timesheet" table like the following:

```
EmployeeID    DateWorked    LaborType    Hours
----------------------------------------------
1             2024-01-01    work         13
1             2024-01-02    work         12
1             2024-01-03    no work      24
1             2024-01-04    work         8
2             2024-01-01    no work      24
2             2024-01-02    work         11
2             2024-01-03    work         8
2             2024-01-04    work         13
```

Every employee will have 1 and only 1 row for every date.  The "no work" hours will always be 24 hours.

We have a rule where an employee is not allowed to work more than 24 hours across 2 consecutive days.  I need to find all instances of this rule violation.  For example, employee 1 violates the rule on dates 2024-01-01 and 2024-01-02 because he worked 25 (13 + 12) hours.  He does not violate the rule on dates 2024-01-02 and 2024-01-03 because the 2024-01-03 row is "no work".  Similarly, employee 2 has no rule violations.

So, I expect output like the following:

```
EmployeeID     ViolationDates            TotalHoursWorked
-------------------------------------------------------
1              2024-01-01, 2024-01-02        25
```

How can I write a query to return this output?

If it helps, below is some T-SQL for the sample data.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.timesheet_mockup
    (
        EmployeeID int
        ,DateWorked date
        ,LaborType varchar(7)
        ,Hours int
    )
    ;

INSERT INTO
    dbo.timesheet_mockup
VALUES
    (1, '2024-01-01', 'work', 13)
    ,(1, '2024-01-02', 'work', 12)
    ,(1, '2024-01-03', 'no work', 24)
    ,(1, '2024-01-04', 'work', 8)
    ,(2, '2024-01-01', 'no work', 24)
    ,(2, '2024-01-02', 'work', 11)
    ,(2, '2024-01-03', 'work', 8)
    ,(2, '2024-01-04', 'work', 13)
;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select *, t1.Hours + t2.Hours as TotalHoursWorked
from dbo.timesheet_mockup t1 inner join dbo.timesheet_mockup t2
    on t2.EmployeeID = t1.EmployeeID
        and t2.DateWorked = dateadd(day, -1, t1.DateWorked)
        and t1.LaborType = 'work' and t2.LaborType = 'work'
where t1.Hours + t2.Hours > 24;
```

You could generalize this across multiple rows very readily with a `cross apply`:

```
select *
from dbo.timesheet_mockup t1 cross apply (
    select sum(Hours) as TotalHoursWorked
    from dbo.timesheet_mockup t2
    where   t2.EmployeeID = t1.EmployeeID
        and t2.DateWorked between dateadd(day, -DAYS, t1.DateWorked) and t1.DateWorked
        and t2.LaborType = 'work'
) as lookback
where t1.LaborType = 'work' and lookback.TotalHoursWorked > MAXHOURS;
```

`sum() over (... range between)` would work except that SQL Server doesn't support this window with `range`. You could still filter the non-work days in the summation but it does assume there are no gaps in the data:

```
with data as (
    select *,
        sum(case when LaborType = 'work' then Hours else 0 end) over (
            partition by EmployeeID order by DateWorked
            rows between 1 preceding and current row) as TotalHoursWorked
    from dbo.timesheet_mockup
)
select * from data where TotalHoursWorked > 24;
```

Eventually this `range` query will work on SQL Server too: https://dbfiddle.uk/W8boAC2t (Postgres example)

And then there's always the simple option to compare `lead()`/`lag()` across adjacent rows and all the relevant columns. (Left as an exercise.)

To guarantee that worked dates are consecutive you could gather the number of non-work hours and then ensure the total was zero:

```
select EmployeeID, DateWorked as LastDateWorked, TotalHoursWorked
from dbo.timesheet_mockup t1 cross apply (
    select
        sum(case when t2.LaborType = 'work'    then Hours else 0 end) as TotalHoursWorked,
        sum(case when t2.LaborType = 'no work' then Hours else 0 end) as TotalHoursOff
    from dbo.timesheet_mockup t2
    where   t2.EmployeeID = t1.EmployeeID
        and t2.DateWorked between dateadd(day, -DAYS, t1.DateWorked) and t1.DateWorked
) as lookback
where t1.LaborType = 'work' and lookback.TotalHoursWorked > MAXHOURS and TotalHoursOff = 0
order by EmployeeID, LastDateWorked;
```

Or by only looking at consecutive dates in the first place (which also eliminates the concern about gaps in the data):

```
with consecutive_dates as (
   select *,
       datediff(day, cast('20000101' as date), DateWorked)
           - row_number() over (partition by EmployeeID order by DateWorked) as grp
   from dbo.timesheet_mockup
   where LaborType = 'work'
), agg as (
    select *,
        count(*) over (
            partition by EmployeeID, grp order by DateWorked
            rows between DAYS preceding and current row) as NumConsecutiveDates,
        sum(Hours) over (
            partition by EmployeeID, grp order by DateWorked
            rows between DAYS preceding and current row) as TotalHoursWorked
    from consecutive_dates
)
select EmployeeID, DateWorked as LastDateWorked, NumConsecutiveDates, TotalHoursWorked
from agg where TotalHoursWorked > MAXHOURS;
```

Comment: I'm curious...  If I needed to generalize this problem to, say, test for a rule across N days (e.g., 72 hours across 7 days), if I use your first solution, would I have to use N self-joins?  If so, would that be advisable (given joins are expensive)?

Comment: @skyline You could join on a range of dates and then sum via grouping. The query would change a bit but it wouldn't be bad.

Comment: I'm experiencing bad performance with the "CROSS APPLY" solution (to test across 7 days), even for a fairly small dataset (~20k rows).  Is there a way to improve this query's performance?

Comment: @skyline1 You might have better luck with the last example. Are there indexes on the table being used?

Comment: No, there aren't any indexes on the table.  And, when I try the "ROWS" solution, I get incorrect results.  For example, for employee 1 on 2024-01-04, it sums rows 2024-01-04 and 2024-01-02.  It should only sum over consecutive work dates.

Comment: @skyline1 I've addressed the consecutive dates question above. These queries appear to run well: https://dbfiddle.uk/srE8_uvg `create index idx on dbo.timesheet_mockup (EmployeeID, DateWorked);` might help.

Comment: I'm getting the expected results now (with your "consecutive dates" solution), and it's much more performant than the "CROSS APPLY" solution on my actual DB.  (The table isn't indexed, and I am not permitted to put one on.)  Thank you.